# Permitir acceso a la página de administración dependiendo del valor de una sesión php

Tags: php, sesiones

me pueden explicar si esta vía es segura o no para la página de administración:

Al abrir la página de administración admin.php, lo único que separa de mostrar la página de no mostrarla es el valor de `$_SESSION["allowAdmin"]`.
Si el valor de esta sesión es `"yes"`, entonces muestra la página, si no redirige a `index.php`.

Me preocupa que alguien pueda crear una sesión de alguna manera y que cualquiera pueda entrar a la página.

Si no, cuál puede ser la vía más segura?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pues así como lo explicas seria algo sencillo:

comparando el valor y mostrando el link de acceso como resultado positivo

```
if($_SESSION["allowAdmin"] == 'yes'){
    echo '<a href="tu URL">Administracion</a>';
}else{
     echo 'Sin Acceso';
}
```

en teoría solo el programador tiene acceso a crear la variable mediante código: `$_SESSION["allowAdmin"]`

aunque tambien existe otro tipos de implementación: tener el valor en una base de datos y hacer la consulta si el usuario tiene permiso; un poco mas lento pero basado en permisos.